# Installing swarm is giving: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)

Tags: swarm, golang

I was getting started with Swarm. I am trying to install Swarm and am following the [official tutorial](http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) for it. Being specific I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt install golang git
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mkdir -p ~/go; echo "export GOPATH=$HOME/go" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
cd go-ethereum
git checkout master
go get github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
```

The last command is giving import error:

> package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does
>   not begin with hostname)

I am not sure what's causing the issue. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**
The issue was with the version of go I installed. The go version I was using was 1.6.(You can the go version by `go version` command).

**Solution:**
The solution is to simply upgrade go to the latest version (I am at go1.8.3).
just replace the second and third line from commands in my problem statement with:

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Comment: I am using 1.9 and having same issue